# What does it mean if weights do not change but b does in gradient descent

Tags: regression, gradient-descent

Let say i have a learning line (y=wx+b). While training b value was constantly decreasing while  there  was  no  significant  change  on  the w value  during  the  subsequent  iterations. In  terms  of  the learning quality, what do the changes on w and b values indicate? Can we say we hit a local minima? Why b changes?

edit: for better pespective I've added a graph of my data. At this stage further iterations just decrease the value of b and there is no change on weights. But as we can see at the graph, line must be steeper. At this point what is the issue? Is my learning rate too small that doesn't acuumulate on weights? Btw There is no programming here just tryin to get my head around this question.

[image: plot]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Linear regression?

Comment: yeah I'm trying linear regression

Comment: there are no local minima in linear ordinary regression

Answer (score 3):

Since linear regression has a well-known closed form solution, almost certainly already implemented in your programming language of choice, this must be a learning exercise. So here is something you can do to find out yourself what is happening:

1. Find the closed-form solution for your data (to use as a reference for your algorithm)
2. Make a contour plot of the sum of squares loss function around the minimum
3. On that plot, plot in the solution path from your algorithm
4. Maybe you can add the plot to your Q, as an edit?

Comment: Thanks for response but this is not a programming problem I'm just trying to get my head around this problem that I encountered with math. The only thing that comes to my mind that maybe learning rate is too small but in that case should `b` go low too right?? I'm confused as hell.

Comment: Are you saying that you do iterations by hand, on paper? Maybe you should explain more clearly, with details (as an edit to your post) what you are doing?

Comment: No no no I'm just sayin hypothetically, what if, there is a situation like that what could be the reason for it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying linear regression, the $w$ parameter controls the slope of the line, and the $b$ parameter controls the location of the line. If the $b$ parameter was changing while the $w$ parameter wasn't, then your data has some bias associated with it. Does this answer your question?

Comment: No, I don't think it's about the dataset. Maybe hyperparams ?